# Is Serverless Proving to be another Player to Kill the OOP after the Event Driven?

Tags: oop, lambda, event-driven, procedural-programming, serverless-architecture

I'm a junior Laravel PHP Developer with a couple of years of industry experience. I am a great lover to learn new things. Nowadays I'm after the "Serverless" :-). We were taught a lot of benefits of the OOP over procedural programming (where the procedural programming was presented as a villain)

- Can someone please help me to understand about this Serverless???
- If it is another player to kill the OOP after the Event Driven?
- If not, then how we can go with the OOP and Serverless together?
- OR Event Driven Procedural is better than OOP?

As I think first the Event Driven (and now the Serverless) was encouraging the developers to move towards the Procedural Programming. but that wasn't the case for the PHP as a backend language but only with the JS with Node.
But now it seems the serverless is another actor came into existing to kill the OOP and encourage the procedural programming to fool the people on the name of "Low Cost" and pushing the developers back to the 80s.

If someone, having knowledge of OOP/Procedural Programming, can help me to understand the Serverless thing as my concern is that we'll have to leave the OOP and which would be a great issue of the maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing apples to oranges.

OOP and procedural are *programming paradigms*.

*Serverless* is an *architectural paradigm* just like *Monolith* and *Microservices*.

They are not mutually exclusive. You can write serverless applications in OOP languages like C# or Java.

Here's a good article: https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html

Comment: Thanks @dashmug for your answer but I'm talking about the functions used on AWS Lambda side to activate/run/execute another app/API.
Also serverless is named by the Microsoft as 'Function' (a procedural programming term) not method (an OPP term) :-)
Hope you've got what I'm talking about.

Comment: They are called "Function" (Azure Functions, AWS Lambda Functions, Google Cloud Functions, etc.) because they use the Function-as-a-service architecture model which is analogous to serverless. While you're at it, I suggest you read about IaaS, PaaS, and FaaS as well.